# Making a long code shorter

Tags: c, structure

people!

I've been told to create next code as homework.
If you compile it - you'l easely see it's purpose. Now, my question is whether there is a way to make it shorter (I'm new to C). I must use structs and struct pointers. This might seem a lame question - sorry for that. 
As well, I would like to know whether it's alright to call "main()" repeatedly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct frac{
    int num;
    int den;
};

int reducer( struct frac *fi ){
    if( fi->num == 0 ) return 0;
    if( fi->den == 1 ) return 1;
    if( fi->num % fi->den == 0 ){
        fi->num /= fi->den;
        fi->den /= fi->den;
        return reducer( fi );
    }
    if( fi->num % 2 == 0 && fi->den % 2 == 0 ){
        fi->num /= 2;
        fi->den /= 2;
        return reducer( fi );
    }
    else if( fi->num % 3 == 0 && fi->den % 3 == 0 ){
        fi->num /= 3;
        fi->den /= 3;
        return reducer( fi );
    }
}

int main(){
    char c , tt;
    struct frac one , two , multi , quot , sum , diff , *o , *t , *m , *q , *s , *d;
    printf( "Please, enter the first fraction, ieg. 3/8:\n" );
    scanf( "%d/%d%c" , &one.num , &one.den , &tt );
    printf( "Now the second fraction (numerator/denominator):\n" );
    scanf( "%d/%d%c" , &two.num , &two.den , &tt );
    o = &one;
    t = &two;
    m = &multi;
    q = &quot;
    s = &sum;
    d = &diff;
    m->num = o->num * t->num; // product numerator
    m->den = o->den * t->den; // product denominator
    q->num = o->num * t->den; // quotient numerator
    q->den = o->den * t->num; // quotient denominator and so on...
    s->num = q->num + q->den;
    s->den = m->den;
    d->num = q->num - q->den;
    d->den = m->den;
    reducer( q );
    reducer( m );
    reducer( s );
    reducer( d );
    printf( "%d/%d + %d/%d = %d/%d\n" , o->num , o->den , t->num , t->den , s->num , s->den );
    printf( "%d/%d - %d/%d = %d/%d\n" , o->num , o->den , t->num , t->den , d->num , d->den );
    printf( "%d/%d * %d/%d = %d/%d\n" , o->num , o->den , t->num , t->den , m->num , m->den );
    printf( "%d/%d : %d/%d = %d/%d\n" , o->num , o->den , t->num , t->den , q->num , q->den );
    printf( "\nWould you like to make another calculation? (y/n):\n" );
    scanf( "%c" , &c );
    if( c == 121 || c == 89 ){
        return main();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I *think* this kind of questions belong to codereview, not stackoverflow. not sure though

Comment: *If you compile it - you'l easely see it's purpose.* Why should we? It is your duty to explain it where we can help, not the other way around.

Comment: I know calling `main()` is illegal in C++, but even if it is allowed in C, it's probably not a good idea, let alone your reasoning for doing so is fundamentally flawed, and you should have a `for` or `while` loop there.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall do you mean to put "main()" includes in a while loop?

Comment: @Constantinius You are right. The code suppose to get two rational numbers and make a simple calculation with their reduced values.

Comment: I mean that you don't need to call `main()` in order to go back to the beginning of it, instead put the parts of main you want to loop over in some sort of loop—that's what loops are for, after all. You probably want a `do {} while();` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

- Use a loop instead of recursion. It's more natural in this scenario, and it doesn't make the stack grow with each iteration:

  ```
  int finish;
  do
  {
      //...
      printf( "\nWould you like to make another calculation? (y/n):\n" );
      scanf( "%c" , &c );
      finish = c != 121 && c == 89;
  }
  while (!finish)
  ```
- You can remove all the pointer declarations and work directly with the fractions themselves.

  ```
  multi.num = one.num * two.num; // product numerator
  // ...
  reducer(&quot)
  ```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong. Can it reduce a fraction 21/49? It does not looks like. The reducer function does not always return. In the reducer function, you will need to compute higher and higher denominators (tip: use a while loop), until it can't be divided anymore.

The main recursion works. But this is a really bad practice and tends to ending up in a messy bugged code. If you put anything before that `return 0` after the recursion, your code will start to behave crazy. Use a while or do...while loop instead.

Further, you may avoid some variables in the main function.

Comment: If I had a fraction of 1/199982239283 - would that be reasonalbe to make a loop of higher and higher denominators?

Comment: Well, in truth the loop would go to min(num, den). However this is still far from ideal if you got something like 5367545/18367213. Ideally you should implement the LCM function.